# How can I add a component to another component in an inherited component?

Tags: qml

I have created a base component in QML that other components inherit from. I would like the base component to have a section where I can insert more components from subcomponents that inherit from the base. How can this be accomplished?

Here is a small example:

**BaseComp.qml**

```
Item {
   GridLayout{
      id: insertComponent
      columns: 1
      anchors.fill: parent
      rowSpacing: 1
      columnSpacing: 1
   }
}
```

**SubComp.qml**

```
BaseComp {
   // I want to make this Rectangle appear inside of insertComponent (defined in BaseComp)
   Rectangle {
      id: insertMeInto_InsertComponent
      Layout.fillWidth: true
   }
}
```

Comment: Whenever anybody asks this question, I ask the counter question, have you ever used `Frame`? You may find that once you understand the `Frame` component, you will avoid a lot of nasty over-engineering.

Comment: The example `BaseComp.qml` is not a good example, since, it would be trivial to rewrite `BaseComp.qml` with the just `GridLayout`, i.e. with `Item` removed, and it would work exactly as you need it. Perhaps, if you show a real example of the problem, I can determine whether `Frame` or an alternate component suits your needs better.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`insertComponent.children`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-item.html#children-prop) as the [`default`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#default-properties) property in `BaseComp`, but this will make every item defined in `BaseComp` a child of the `GridLayout`.

> Default properties can be useful for reassigning the children of an
> item. For example:
>
> ```
> Item {
>     default property alias content: inner.children
>
>     Item {
>         id: inner
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> By setting the default property alias to inner.children, any object
> assigned as a child of the outer item is automatically reassigned as a
> child of the inner item.

---

**BaseComp.qml**

```
Item {
    default property alias content: insertComponent.children

    GridLayout {
        id: insertComponent
        columns: 1
        anchors.fill: parent
        rowSpacing: 1
        columnSpacing: 1
    }
}
```